# '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor' this error is happening when i use redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, import, export, redux-form

when i try to use redux-form library and imported it this error is poping:

```
App.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: _streams_StreamCreate__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor
```

here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class StreamCreate extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return <div>StreamCreate</div>
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'streamCreate'
})(StreamCreate);
```

how do I solve this?

I appreciate in advance any help.

Comment: I can't really help you with the problem, but just want to make sure: you are aware that redux-form has been deprecated by the author years ago, right? It says so directly on the first page of the homepage of Redux-Form. Unfortunately many tutorials still show it to this day. If you are following such a tutorial it might also be showing you outdated ways of using Redux. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, createStore or connect. Check the official tutorial in that case: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: you 're right, i was using outdated materials. thanks.